# Error in writing dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to have a sp with dynamic query like this,

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)='
declare @DateParam datetime
set @DateParam=getdate()
select * from tblOrders
where Order_site='TSN' 
AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)'
```

when writing like this i have received in the quotation part of 'TSN'. It doesnt allow single quotes here. How can i achieve the where condition?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: `where Order_site=''TSN''` Try having like this.

Comment: As @Viki888 demonstrated above, escape your single quotes by doubling them.

Answer (score 2):

you need to build it as a string.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)='
declare @DateParam datetime
set @DateParam=getdate()
select * from tblOrders
where Order_site=''TSN'' 
AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are breaking your main nvarchar because of 'TSN', try like this

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)='

declare @DateParam datetime
set @DateParam=getdate()

select * from tblOrders
where Order_site=' + 'TSN' + 
'AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with dynamic sql in stored procedure try something like this . It is better to use different variables for main select query and dynamic where query which can be extended easily . using this approach it will be easy to maintain when you proc becomes lengthy

```
        declare @finalquery varchar(max)
        declare @mainSelectquery nvarchar(500);
        declare @whereCondtions varchar (1000);
        declare @DateParam datetime
        set @mainSelectquery=''
        set @whereCondtions =''

        set @finalquery =''

        set @DateParam=getdate()
        set @mainSelectquery = 'select * from tblOrders  where 1=1  '

        set @whereCondtions =  ' and Order_site =''TSN'''

        set @whereCondtions = @whereCondtions + ' AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)' 

        set @finalquery =( @mainSelectquery + @whereCondtions)

        print @finalquery

     ---- You can further extend this by adding more where condition based on the parameter pass in stored proc 
  if (@OrderID !=0)
  begin 
     set @whereCondtions =  ' OrderID='+str ( @stateRefID )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to escaping your string with double quotes, you can try using [**QUOTENAME()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
declare @val nvarchar(max) = 'TSN'

declare @query nvarchar(max)='
declare @DateParam datetime
set @DateParam=getdate()
select * from tblOrders
where Order_site= ' + quotename(@val, '''') + 
' AND CAST(ORDER_APPROVED_DATE_LT AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)'

select @query
```